# assistance with installing TeX packages with WinEdt on my laptop

Tags: installing

I have recently posted a fragment of code asking for help with understanding why it won't compile, but the user cfr pointed out that I shouldn't have posted all of that code because it would involve a breach of confidentiality (since it was a reviewer's report I was writing and may possibly have contained enough information to identify the paper). So I apologise for making that stupid mistake, and I thank cfr for pointing that out, and I have now deleted the post and contacted the administrators of the site asking if any other action needs to be taken. I hope that that was the correct thing to do there.

Others have said the problem probably lies with me not having TeX code installed on my machine so I was wondering if I can find out where to get TeX packages to add to my WinEdt editor on my laptop.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Is the problem that you did not succeed in installing TeX and an editor and thus are not able to compile any code; or are you able to compile other code, but not the specified document (so it contains a mistake)?

Comment: In the latter case: if you add code to your question, make sure to post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: It's Windows 7 Home Premium on a Vaio machine. I didn't have any problem with compiling files in the past. I use the WinEdt editor and I used to be able to compile everything just fine.

Comment: With the code that I posted before, a friend of mine said it compiled perfectly fine on his machine. And also I was able to get very similar code to compile on my own machine quite recently. It's possible the laptop might have developed some kind of fault, like corruption fo the hard disk or something. I don't know.

Comment: I think I'll probably just go to the university and ask them if they can let me use one of their machines to compile it, see if I can solve it that way. Thanks for your suggestions. I don't know what's going on with this laptop, but it's very old, I may just need to get a new one.